# cmake find custom package

Tags: c++, cmake

I wrote a series of package in a folder and I want to write a program that uses them. The main thing is that I want to keep the folders at the same level so to have a more independent management.
For example I have a package called brisk that have to be used by another package called place_recognition

```
cpp
 |
 -- brisk
 |  |
 |  --CMakeLists.txt
 |  |
 |  --release
 |  |  |
 |  |  --lib
  --etc...
 -- place_recognition
 |  |
 |  --cmake
 |  |
 |  -- CMakeLists.txt
 |  |
 |  -- src
 |  | 
 |  -- include
```

I wrote a FindBrisk.cmake file and I have added it to my "place_recognition" project.

get_filename_component(BRISK_CURRENT_CONFIG_DIR
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)

```
set(BRISK_EXPORTED_BUILD_DIR ${BRISK_CURRENT_CONFIG_DIR})
get_filename_component(BRISK_EXPORTED_SOURCE_DIR
  ${BRISK_EXPORTED_BUILD_DIR}/../../brisk/ ABSOLUTE)


set(BRISK_INCLUDE_DIR "${BRISK_EXPORTED_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
set(BRISK_LIBRARY_DIR "${BRISK_EXPORTED_SOURCE_DIR}/release/lib")
set(BRISK_FOUND True)
set(BRISK_LIBRARIES "${BRISK_EXPORTED_SOURCE_DIR}/release/lib/libbrisk.a")
set(AGAST_INCLUDE_DIR "${BRISK_EXPORTED_SOURCE_DIR}/agast/include")
set(AGAST_LIBRARIES "${BRISK_EXPORTED_SOURCE_DIR}/release/lib/libagast.a")
set(AGAST_FOUND True)

mark_as_advanced(BRISK_INCLUDE_DIR BRISK_LIBRARY_DIR BRISK_LIBRARIES AGAST_INCLUDE_DIR AGAST_LIBRARIES)
```

I include it in my CMakeLists.txt that is reported here

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project(place_recognition)

#set up the output tree
set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

find_package(Brisk REQUIRED)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories(BEFORE ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}) 

if(BRISK_FOUND)
  message(STATUS "Found BRISK in " ${BRISK_INCLUDE_DIR})
else(BRISK_FOUND)
  message(STATUS "BRISK NOT FOUND")
endif(BRISK_FOUND)




# copy all needed files to binary dir (when cmake)
file(GLOB files_needed
    dataset/*
)
file(COPY ${files_needed} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})

include_directories(
  include
  ${BRISK_INCLUDE_DIR}
  ${AGAST_INCLUDE_DIR}
)



add_definitions(-mssse3 -DAGAST_GLOG -Werror -Wextra -Wall -pedantic -std=c++0x)

add_executable(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  src/main.cpp
)

link_directories(
    ${BRISK_LIBRARY_DIR}
)


target_link_libraries(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${OpenCV_LIBS}
  ${AGAST_LIBRARIES}
  ${BRISK_LIBRARIES}
)
```

However, I get  a strange behaviour. When I try to compile the code the compiler is not able to find the dependencies of the brisk package and I am asked to include them explicitly in my cmake file, in my example I had to do it with OpenCV. Since, brisk uses also GLOG now I get the following error when trying to compile

> Linking CXX executable ../bin/place_recognition
>   /home/andrea/development/cpp/brisk/release/lib/libbrisk.a(brisk-scale-space.cc.o):
>   In function
>   `brisk::BriskScaleSpace::GetKeypoints(std::vector<cv::KeyPoint,
>   std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >*)':
>   brisk-scale-space.cc:(.text+0x4690): undefined reference to`
>   google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int,
>   google::CheckOpString const&)' brisk-scale-space.cc:(.text+0x469d):
>   undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
>   /home/andrea/development/cpp/brisk/release/lib/libbrisk.a(brisk-layer.cc.o):
>   In function`brisk::BriskLayer::GetAgastPoints(unsigned char,
>   std::vector >*)':
>   brisk-layer.cc:(.text+0x14c): undefined reference to
>   `google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int,
>   google::CheckOpString const&)' brisk-layer.cc:(.text+0x156): undefined
>   reference to`google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
>   /home/andrea/development/cpp/brisk/release/lib/libbrisk.a(brisk-layer.cc.o):
>   In function `brisk::BriskLayer::BriskLayer(cv::Mat const&, unsigned
>   char, unsigned char, float, float)': brisk-layer.cc:(.text+0x29ef):
>   undefined reference to`vtable for agast::OastDetector9_16'
>   brisk-layer.cc:(.text+0x2b4d): undefined reference to `vtable for
>   agast::AgastDetector5_8'
>   /home/andrea/development/cpp/brisk/release/lib/libbrisk.a(brisk-layer.cc.o):
>   In function`brisk::BriskLayer::BriskLayer(brisk::BriskLayer const&,
>   int, unsigned char, unsigned char)': brisk-layer.cc:(.text+0x32e3):
>   undefined reference to `vtable for agast::OastDetector9_16'
>   brisk-layer.cc:(.text+0x3456): undefined reference to`vtable for
>   agast::AgastDetector5_8'
>   /home/andrea/development/cpp/brisk/release/lib/libbrisk.a(image-down-sampling.cc.o):
>   In function `brisk::Halfsample16(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&)':
>   image-down-sampling.cc:(.text+0xc4e): undefined reference to`
>   google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int,
>   google::CheckOpString const&)' image-down-sampling.cc:(.text+0xc56):
>   undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
>   image-down-sampling.cc:(.text+0xc5e): undefined reference to`
>   google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
>   image-down-sampling.cc:(.text+0xcab): undefined reference to
>   `google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int,
>   google::CheckOpString const&)' image-down-sampling.cc:(.text+0xcb3):
>   undefined reference to`google::LogMessage::stream()'
>   image-down-sampling.cc:(.text+0xd02): undefined reference to
>   `google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int,
>   google::CheckOpString const&)' image-down-sampling.cc:(.text+0xd0a):
>   undefined reference to`google::LogMessage::stream()'
>   /home/andrea/development/cpp/brisk/release/lib/libbrisk.a(image-down-sampling.cc.o):
>   In function `brisk::Halfsample8(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&)':
>   image-down-sampling.cc:(.text+0x1227): undefined reference to`
>   google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int,
>   google::CheckOpString const&)' image-down-sampling.cc:(.text+0x122f):
>   undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
>   image-down-sampling.cc:(.text+0x1237): undefined reference to`
>   google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
>   image-down-sampling.cc:(.text+0x1280): undefined reference to
>   `google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int,
>   google::CheckOpString const&)' image-down-sampling.cc:(.text+0x1288):
>   undefined reference to`google::LogMessage::stream()'
>   /home/andrea/development/cpp/brisk/release/lib/libbrisk.a(image-down-sampling.cc.o):
>   In function `brisk::Twothirdsample8(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&)':
>   image-down-sampling.cc:(.text+0x168f): undefined reference to`
>   google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int,
>   google::CheckOpString const&)' image-down-sampling.cc:(.text+0x1697):
>   undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
>   image-down-sampling.cc:(.text+0x169f): undefined reference to`
>   google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
>   image-down-sampling.cc:(.text+0x16e5): undefined reference to
>   `google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int,
>   google::CheckOpString const&)' image-down-sampling.cc:(.text+0x16ed):
>   undefined reference to`google::LogMessage::stream()'
>   /home/andrea/development/cpp/brisk/release/lib/libbrisk.a(image-down-sampling.cc.o):
>   In function `std::string* google::MakeCheckOpString<int, int>(int
>   const&, int const&, char const*)':
>   image-down-sampling.cc:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x15):
>   undefined reference to`
>   google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::CheckOpMessageBuilder(char
>   const*)'
>   image-down-sampling.cc:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x2c):
>   undefined reference to
>   `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::ForVar2()'
>   image-down-sampling.cc:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x40):
>   undefined reference to`
>   google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::NewString()'
>   image-down-sampling.cc:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x4f):
>   undefined reference to
>   `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::~CheckOpMessageBuilder()'
>   image-down-sampling.cc:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x68):
>   undefined reference to`
>   google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::~CheckOpMessageBuilder()'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make[2]: ***
>   [../bin/place_recognition] Error 1 make[1]: ***
>   [CMakeFiles/place_recognition.dir/all] Error 2 make: *** [all] Error 2

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks
Andrea

Comment: If `eigen` is part of your tree, what point to search it? just use it.

Comment: It is at the same level of the camera_simulation folder. How can I use it? you mean by doing something like

#include "../../eigen/Eigen/src/etc?"

Comment: Use top level CMakeLIsts.txt, where set dependecies of targets, plus cmake support relative paths, so you can use "../eidgen"

Comment: I actually do not have a top level cmake target (and I would like not to have it), that is why I am trying to use the find package function

Comment: Actually, **asking for guide is offtopic on SO**. You can try to follow [this one](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries#Writing_find_modules). Also you can check existing `find*.cmake` modules shipped with CMake: most of them are quite simple for undestand and follow guide above.

Comment: I will try to follow it again. I was not able to make it work. In case I update my question with the file I made.

Comment: I have solved the problem with my eigens installing the package, but now I have the same problem with another package. I Updated my question.